# Is using triggers best solution for this scenario

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, triggers

A large SQL transactional database has more than 100 tables (and it will grow). One of them is called **Order**. Then, there is another table **WorkLoad** which derives from Order and many other joined table which contains a list of all active order. Every time an order record is created, if it meets certain conditions, it should be instantly inserted into WorkLoad table. And finally, there is a third table **WorkLoadAggregation** which displays aggregated data grouped by date and shop and it is completely built from WorkLoad table. WorkLoadAggregation should also display live data meaning that if a record is inserted in WorkLoad table then matching date/shop aggregation should also be updated.

My idea was to handle this by following triggers:

1. When record is **inserted in Order table**, trigger calls stored procedure which inserts record into WorkLoad table
2. When **Order record is deleted** trigger deletes the record from WorkLoad table
3. When **Order record is updated** in a way that it doesn't meet WorkLoad conditions, trigger deletes the record from WorkLoad table
4. When record is **inserted/deleted/updated in WorkLoad** table, trigger calls stored procedure which updates matching date/shop aggregated record in WorkLoadAggregation table

I haven't used triggers that much in such large transaction dbs and for such frequent calls. Is there anything bad in this approach? My biggest concern is usage of "chained triggers", meaning that trigger on one table activates trigger on another table. I've been reading few articles which state that developers should be very cautious when using triggers. Are there any better solutions? Should I consider any NoSQL solution?

Database is hosted on SQL Server 2012.

Note: In case 5) the stored procedure that's called contains a CTE (case someone suggests using an indexed view)

Comment: if you use triggers just pay attention to this tip: *triggers are always a part of the transaction which fires the trigger* and take care when you use the roll back or commit in the triggers or you have explicit transaction in the trigger. I mean if you decide to use triggers for this scenario think on and manage the transactions well, this was the main tip in my view

Answer (score 0):

It is a little difficult to provide a more concrete opinion, but based on the presentation of the problem space.  I would not recommend this solution, as it would be difficult to test effectively and I can see this causing issues under times of high load.  Also it is really hard to quantify the total impact as I am not sure what the read load would look like and how many other processes may need information out of those tables.

Based on how you have described the problem, and the fact that you asked about NoSQL approaches, I assume that eventual consistency is not much of a concern so I would recommend a more EventDriven Architecture.  Keep in mind that this may mean a significant re-write of your current implementation but would definitely allow for better domain decomposition and scaling.

Comment: "and I can see this causing issues under times of high load" - what type of issues?